# Is kothing-editor extinct?

Tags: npm, package, npm-package

I have kothing editor on my project, but now, when I try to install the npm packages in my server, it gives me this error:

npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions for kothing-editor

So I just want to know if it is really extinct or I'm doing something wrong?

I searched in the npm website and the package is not there.